# How do I retrieve a 4 week moving average by day of week and by hour?

Tags: mysql

I want to return the rolling/moving average of hour of day over day of the week, for a range of weeks in the past, for a range of dates.

The lookback for each date in the range has an offset and a span weeks. For each date in the range I want to pull the values from previous weeks, using a starting week offest, and a number of weeks to span into the past.

For instance, Oct 1 - Oct 7, looking back 4 weeks, starting 1 week back.

Each day of October 1st through October 7th, look back over a span of 4 weeks, starting one week prior, and take the sum of the count for each hour, for each occurance of that day's same dayofweek (1-7), in the lookback span.

and then we can do some math with that, in this case get the average entry density, or the average number of entries per hour by day of the week for each date in the range.

Start with October 1st in that range.

This should produce 24 rows, with:

date column filled with October 1st(2017-10-01),

a dayofweek column, (1 for sundays),

a count column, with the sum of entries per hour bucket, for each instance of dayofweek(1), over the look back span (4weeks)

a range of Sundays prior returned for Oct 1st, which a Sunday, is (Yoda tax) .

So it would take the hourly number of entries from September 3rd,10th,17th and 24th, and calculate the average for each hour of the day, over those 4 sundays. The value in the response for October 1st, 10am would be sum of the rows from 10am on the 3rd,10th,17th and 24th.

That's for October 1st.

For October 2nd in that range, it would pull 24 rows, with the date column as 2017-10-02, the dayofweek column(2 for Mondays), and average for each hour from the lookback distance, which would include:
 September 4th,
 September 11th,
 September 18th

Selecting count for HOUR( datecolumn ), from each day, the sum would be divided by the number of days over the lookback range for which each hour segment has values.

Schema Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `datetimecolumn` datetime<br/>
) 

INSERT INTO MyTable
    (`datetimecolumn`)
VALUES
    ('2015-08-01 00:01:00'),
    ('2015-08-01 00:21:00'),
    ('2015-08-01 01:25:00'),
    ('2015-08-01 01:39:00'),
    ('2015-08-01 02:11:00'),
    ('2015-08-01 03:01:00'),

    ## more here, several randomly timed entries in most hours of each day
```

several thousand entries per month.

```
    ('2017-10-16 01:01:00'),
    ('2017-10-16 02:11:00'),
    ('2017-10-16 02:21:00'),
    ('2017-10-16 03:01:00'),
    ('2017-10-16 05:43:00'),
    ('2017-10-16 06:21:00')
;
```

Desired Results for 2017-09-30 to 2017-10-02:

```
|     Date   | DOW | hour_of_day | Avg_Num_Entries | 
|------------|-----|-------------| ----------------| 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          00 |              12 | 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          01 |              11 | 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          02 |              14 | 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          03 |              12 | 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          04 |              11 | 
| 2017-09-30 |   7 |          05 |              14 | 
( ..24 total rows for DAYOFWEEK 7 )

| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          00 |              12 | 
| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          01 |              11 | 
| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          02 |              14 | 
| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          03 |              12 | 
| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          04 |              11 | 
| 2017-10-01 |   1 |          05 |              14 | 
( ..24 total rows for DAYOFWEEK 1 )

| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          00 |              12 | 
| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          01 |              11 | 
| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          02 |              14 | 
| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          03 |              12 | 
| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          04 |              11 | 
| 2017-10-02 |   2 |          05 |              14 | 
( ..24 total rows for DAYOFWEEK 2 )
```

I am currently working with this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(c.datetimecolum) datetimecolum,
  t.sq_datetimecolum,
  t.sq_hour,
  t.sq_count
FROM
  calls c
  INNER JOIN(
              SELECT
                DATE(datetimecolum) sq_datetimecolum,
                DAYOFWEEK(datetimecolum) sq_dow,
                HOUR(datetimecolum) sq_hour,
                COUNT(*) sq_count
              FROM
                calls
              GROUP BY sq_datetimecolum,sq_dow,sq_hour
            ) AS t
    ON
      DATE(t.sq_datetimecolum) <= DATE_SUB(
          DATE(c.datetimecolum),
          INTERVAL 1 WEEK
      ) AND DATE(t.sq_datetimecolum) >= DATE_SUB(
          DATE(c.datetimecolum),
          INTERVAL 4 WEEK
      ) AND DAYOFWEEK(t.sq_datetimecolum) = DAYOFWEEK(DATE(c.datetimecolum))

WHERE  DATE(c.datetimecolum) >= '2017-08-01' AND DATE(c.datetimecolum) <= '2017-08-02'
GROUP BY DATE(c.datetimecolum),DATE(t.sq_datetimecolum),DAYOFWEEK(t.sq_datetimecolum),t.sq_hour
ORDER BY DATE(c.datetimecolum),t.sq_datetimecolum,t.sq_hour
```

which is producing this output for the date range 2017-08-01 to 2017-08-02 :

```
|    datetimecolum     | sq_datetimecolum | sq_hour | sq_count |
|----------------------|------------------|---------|----------|
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       0 |       18 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       1 |       11 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       2 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       3 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       4 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       5 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       6 |        4 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       7 |        1 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       8 |        4 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |       9 |        6 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      10 |        6 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      11 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      12 |       11 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      13 |       21 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      14 |       44 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      15 |       52 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      16 |       32 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      17 |       26 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      18 |       22 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      19 |       25 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      20 |       14 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      21 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      22 |       10 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-04    |      23 |        6 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       0 |       21 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       1 |       21 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       2 |       12 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       3 |       12 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       4 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       5 |        4 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       6 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       7 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |       8 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      10 |        5 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      11 |       14 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      12 |       50 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      13 |       99 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      14 |      117 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      15 |      132 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      16 |      101 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      17 |       89 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      18 |       81 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      19 |      110 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      20 |      120 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      21 |      119 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      22 |       85 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-11    |      23 |       35 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       0 |       44 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       1 |       33 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       2 |       11 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       3 |       13 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       4 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       5 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       6 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       7 |        5 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       8 |        7 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |       9 |       10 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      10 |        5 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      11 |       16 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      12 |       39 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      13 |       67 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      14 |      128 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      15 |      133 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      16 |      129 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      17 |      120 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      18 |      102 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      19 |       93 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      20 |      112 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      21 |       81 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      22 |       74 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-18    |      23 |       43 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       0 |       32 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       1 |       19 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       2 |        9 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       3 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       4 |        6 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       5 |        8 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       6 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       7 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       8 |        3 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |       9 |        2 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      10 |        5 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      11 |       15 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      12 |       39 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      13 |       71 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      14 |       84 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      15 |      100 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      16 |       92 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      17 |       58 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      18 |       59 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      19 |       70 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      20 |       80 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      21 |       83 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      22 |       60 |
|       2017-08-01     |    2017-07-25    |      23 |       40 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       0 |        7 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       1 |        6 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       2 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       3 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       4 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       5 |        1 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       6 |        2 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       7 |        1 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       8 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |       9 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      10 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      11 |       13 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      12 |       50 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      13 |       97 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      14 |      125 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      15 |      139 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      16 |      106 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      17 |      106 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      18 |       93 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      19 |       80 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      20 |       86 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      21 |       68 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      22 |       53 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-05    |      23 |       26 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       0 |       24 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       1 |       21 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       2 |       16 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       3 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       4 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       5 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       6 |        1 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       7 |        2 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       8 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |       9 |       15 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      10 |        7 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      11 |       12 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      12 |       44 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      13 |       60 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      14 |       73 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      15 |      119 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      16 |      100 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      17 |       87 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      18 |       58 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      19 |       85 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      20 |       96 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      21 |       79 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      22 |       61 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-12    |      23 |       25 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       0 |       27 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       1 |       24 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       2 |       20 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       3 |       12 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       4 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       5 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       6 |        2 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       7 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       8 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |       9 |        4 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      10 |       10 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      11 |       11 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      12 |       33 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      13 |       75 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      14 |      107 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      15 |       98 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      16 |       68 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      17 |       71 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      18 |       96 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      19 |      102 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      20 |       86 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      21 |       67 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      22 |       54 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-19    |      23 |       29 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       0 |       35 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       1 |       16 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       2 |       11 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       3 |        8 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       4 |        6 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       5 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       6 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       7 |        3 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       8 |        7 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |       9 |        2 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      10 |        5 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      11 |       11 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      12 |       41 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      13 |       52 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      14 |       76 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      15 |       83 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      16 |       97 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      17 |       71 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      18 |       56 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      19 |       69 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      20 |       45 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      21 |       67 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      22 |       68 |
|       2017-08-02     |    2017-07-26    |      23 |       39 |
```

I'm very close. This is producing the hourly number of entries for each dayofweek from 4 weeks prior.

I just need to get those hourly totals to sum across the 4 days and then divide by four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses 2 subqueries:

**Subquery 1** controls the final output by forming unique rows of date, day of week and hour across a nominated date range. That date range uses a parameter for the starting date of that range, that the same parameter is used in the next subquery. (*nb: It is assumed here that all the required daysofweek and hours will be present in the data. If not, another approach would be needed to supply all the needed daysofweek and hours*).

**Subquery 2** filters backward from the start point used above, for a number of weeks that can be controlled by a parameter. This date range is then summarized by dayofweek and hour.

The 2 subqueries are then joined on dayofweek and hour so that the averages become aligned to ate, dayofweek and hour. Note that the date range used in each subquery are  mutually exclusive so that counts are accurate.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e71ae9/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `start_time` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    (`start_time`)
VALUES
('2017-08-05 00:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 00:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 00:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 01:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 01:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 01:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 02:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 02:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 02:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 03:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 03:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 03:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 04:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 04:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 04:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 05:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 05:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 05:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 06:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 06:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 06:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 07:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 07:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 07:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 08:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 08:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 08:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 09:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 09:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 09:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 10:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 10:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 10:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 11:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 11:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 11:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 12:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 12:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 12:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 13:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 13:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 13:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 14:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 14:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 14:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 15:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 15:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 15:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 16:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 16:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 16:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 17:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 17:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 17:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 18:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 18:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 18:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 19:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 19:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 19:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 20:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 20:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 20:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 21:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 21:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 21:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 22:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 22:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 22:29:00'),
('2017-08-05 23:01:00'),
('2017-08-05 23:15:00'),
('2017-08-05 23:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 00:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 00:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 00:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 01:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 01:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 01:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 02:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 02:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 02:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 03:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 03:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 03:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 04:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 04:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 04:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 05:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 05:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 05:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 06:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 06:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 06:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 07:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 07:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 07:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 08:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 08:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 08:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 09:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 09:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 09:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 10:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 10:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 10:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 11:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 11:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 11:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 12:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 12:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 12:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 13:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 13:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 13:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 14:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 14:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 14:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 15:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 15:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 15:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 16:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 16:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 16:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 17:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 17:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 17:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 18:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 18:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 18:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 19:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 19:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 19:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 20:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 20:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 20:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 21:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 21:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 21:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 22:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 22:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 22:29:00'),
('2017-08-06 23:01:00'),
('2017-08-06 23:15:00'),
('2017-08-06 23:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 00:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 00:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 00:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 01:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 01:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 01:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 02:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 02:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 02:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 03:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 03:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 03:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 04:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 04:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 04:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 05:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 05:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 05:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 06:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 06:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 06:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 07:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 07:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 07:29:00'),
('2017-08-03 08:01:00'),
('2017-08-03 08:15:00'),
('2017-08-03 08:29:00'),

('2017-08-12 00:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 00:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 00:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 01:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 01:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 01:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 02:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 02:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 02:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 03:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 03:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 03:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 04:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 04:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 04:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 05:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 05:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 05:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 06:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 06:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 06:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 07:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 07:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 07:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 08:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 08:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 08:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 09:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 09:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 09:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 10:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 10:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 10:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 11:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 11:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 11:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 12:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 12:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 12:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 13:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 13:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 13:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 14:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 14:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 14:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 15:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 15:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 15:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 16:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 16:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 16:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 17:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 17:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 17:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 18:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 18:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 18:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 19:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 19:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 19:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 20:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 20:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 20:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 21:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 21:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 21:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 22:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 22:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 22:29:00'),
('2017-08-12 23:01:00'),
('2017-08-12 23:15:00'),
('2017-08-12 23:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 00:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 00:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 00:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 01:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 01:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 01:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 02:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 02:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 02:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 03:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 03:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 03:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 04:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 04:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 04:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 05:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 05:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 05:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 06:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 06:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 06:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 07:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 07:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 07:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 08:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 08:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 08:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 09:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 09:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 09:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 10:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 10:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 10:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 11:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 11:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 11:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 12:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 12:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 12:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 13:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 13:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 13:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 14:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 14:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 14:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 15:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 15:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 15:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 16:01:00'),
('2017-08-13 16:15:00'),
('2017-08-13 16:29:00'),
('2017-08-13 17:01:00')
;
```

**Query**:

```
set @start_at := '2017-08-12'
set @num_weeks:= 4
set @sub_nw_st := date_sub(@start_at, INTERVAL (7 * @num_weeks) DAY)

select
     c.dt, c.dow, c.hr
     , coalesce(h.c_count,0) + c.c_count c_count
     , coalesce(h.dt_count,0) + 1 dt_count 
     , (coalesce(h.c_count,0) + c.c_count) / (coalesce(h.dt_count,0) + 1) Avg_Num_Entries
from (
    select
        date(start_time) dt
      , dayofweek(start_time) dow
      , hour(start_time) hr
      , count(*) c_count
    from MyTable
    where start_time >= @start_at and start_time < date_add(@start_at,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    group by
          dt, dow, hr
    ) c
LEFT JOIN (
      select
          dayofweek(start_time) dow
        , hour(start_time) hr
        , count(distinct date(start_time)) dt_count
        , count(*) c_count
      from MyTable
      where start_time >= @sub_nw_st and start_time < @start_at
      group by
            dow, hr
      ) h
          ON c.dow = h.dow and c.hr = h.hr
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e71ae9/2/3)**:

```
|         dt | dow | hr | c_count | dt_count | Avg_Num_Entries |
|------------|-----|----|---------|----------|-----------------|
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  0 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  1 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  2 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  3 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  4 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  5 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  6 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  7 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  8 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 |  9 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 10 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 11 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 12 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 13 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 14 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 15 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 16 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 17 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 18 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 19 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 20 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 21 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 22 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-12 |   7 | 23 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  0 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  1 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  2 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  3 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  4 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  5 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  6 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  7 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  8 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 |  9 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 10 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 11 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 12 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 13 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 14 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 15 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 16 |       6 |        2 |               3 |
| 2017-08-13 |   1 | 17 |       4 |        2 |               2 |
```

Comment: This is very close. I need it to look back 5 weeks for each day in a custom span of dates. What I needed was the combination of sub_selects and and joins to get that count. I've got a version of this subselect join going with my 5 week lookback date_sub and it's producing the right totals for all 4 days, but some dates are reporting 3 instead of 4 dates, so I need to do some more looking. 

However that is currently only working to look back and get averages for one date, not a span of dates. I'll have another look shortly. It's very close.

Comment: I have used the start date of sub1, as the end date for sub2, so if you want an OVERALL 4 week span, then then number of backward weeks would be 3 (assuming you are using my parameters).  setting-up good predictable test data is the key to proving this this IMO.

Comment: just caught new changes, will report soon, TY!

Comment: And suggestion for missing hours in the data? Every day will have data, but some hours do not. Right now it appears that if an hour for one of the days in the week is not represented, it just reduces the number dt_count and still gives the correct average for the hour.

Comment: You would have to generate a 24 * (num days of range)  result, then left join the data to that. If you are always reporting a preset duration (1 week, 1 month) you could create a table for this - or generate it on the fly using a "tally table" or a set of unions to achieve the same thing.

Comment: The question is for a moving average that looks back a set number of weeks for each day in the query. This appears to look back over a static range.

Comment: "where start_time >= @sub_nw_st and start_time < @start_at" in the second query needs to be :

where 
start_time >= DATE_SUB( c.dt, INTERVAL 4 WEEK) )
   AND 
start_time  <= DATE_SUB( c.dt, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) )

Comment: A. It is not a static range. That is the very reason for using parsmeters, so it is easy to slter the range.  B. If you make that period 4 weeks, c onsider that this is ADDED to the first subquery,  which is also 1 werk.  That is 5 werks in total. It's up to you to choose.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This is my current solution, based on the accepted answer.

```
SET @start_at := '2017-08-01';
  SET @end_at := '2017-08-02';
  SET @lookback_offset := 1;
  SET @lookback_span := 4;

  SELECT
    c.*,
    count(distinct date(h.dt_col)) days_counted,
    count(hour(h.dt_col)) dowhodt,
    count(hour(h.dt_col))/count(distinct date(h.dt_col)) dowhodma
  FROM
    (SELECT
       DATE(dt_col) dt,
       DAYOFWEEK(dt_col) dow,
       HOUR(dt_col) hr
     FROM
       MyTable
     GROUP BY dt , dow , hr) c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
  ) h ON
        (DAYOFWEEK(DATE(h.dt_col)) = c.dow)
        AND
        (HOUR(h.dt_col) = c.hr)
        AND
        (DATE(h.dt_col) >= DATE_SUB(c.dt, INTERVAL @lookback_span WEEK))
        AND
        (DATE(h.dt_col) <= DATE_SUB(c.dt, INTERVAL @lookback_offset WEEK))


  WHERE DATE( c.dt ) >= @start_at AND DATE( c.dt ) <= @end_at
  GROUP BY  dt,dow,hr
```